# Why does my program not work after more than 3 inputs to the array?

Tags: arrays, c

I created an array to obtain different numbers. Then I summed up the numbers inside the array by chosing two of them each time to check whether a summation is equal to global variable "target". However, when I input more than 3 numbers inside the array, my code enters a loop and I don't know why. How do I eliminate this problem in my code? Thank you.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int array_size;
int target=6;
int counter=0;
int temp;

void main(){
    printf("Enter the quantity of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d",&array_size);
    int *arr=(int *)malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<array_size;i++){
        printf("Enter element %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for (int x=0 ; x <array_size-1 ; x++){
        counter++;
        temp=counter;
        for(counter; counter < array_size ; counter++){
            if ((arr[x]+arr[counter])==target){
                printf("\nThe indices are %d %d", x , counter);
            
            }
            else{ 
                counter=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

**Here is the output when I enter 3 numbers**

```
Enter the quantity of numbers: 3
Enter element 1: 1
Enter element 2: 2
Enter element 3: 5

The indices are 0 2
```

**because in the array first and third elements sums up to 6 (target=6)**

[and this is the problem when I enter 4 inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyhfO.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please show what you enter when the program *isn't* working?

Comment: `for(counter; ...` Could you please explain what do you think it's doing?

Comment: It doesn't always execute the `counter=temp;`. Instead if trying to recycle the variable, use another one. Use `temp` as the inner loop control instead. It is too complicated: you just need a simple pair of nested loops, and print the indices where the sum is correct.

Comment: `for(int x=0; x<array_size; x++) for(int y=x+1; y<array_size; y++) if(arr[x] + arr[y] == target) printf("Indices %d %d\n", x, y);`

Comment: counter is the index of the second element that is going to summed up with the first element

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In the linked example, `counter` gets stuck on `2`.

Answer (score 1):

As Weather Vane has mentioned try to keep your code simple, there is no need to use `counter` and `temp`, all you need is two nested for loops to check if two array elements are equal to a target element.

Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size, target = 6;

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int array[size];

    // Input array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    // Check for pairs
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[i] + array[j] == target) {
                printf("Pair found: %d and %d\n", array[i], array[j]);
                found = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        printf("No pairs found.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to find two numbers which their summation is equal to the target variable.

Comment: Yes @BaranKahraman this is exactly what my code does. Or are you trying to say something else?